# can not pivot table sql

Tags: sql, pivot

i want to pivot table but i get some error about this image
[image]

this is my code

```
SELECT   ARCBG_Abbrev
        ,ARCIM_Code
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN TAR_Code = 'O' THEN ITP_Price   
             ELSE 0 END) AS O
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN TAR_Code = 'I' THEN ITP_Price ELSE 0 END)
                    AS I
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN TAR_Code = 'F' THEN ITP_Price ELSE 0 END) 
                    AS F
FROM    SYSTEM.VS_OrderItem
WHERE   (ARCIM_Code = '010004')
GROUP BY ARCBG_Abbrev, ARCIM_Code
```

i try to distinct column to check value in column is same in every row where ARCIM_Code = 010004 .it's the same value in column ARCBG_Abbrev. Can you check my pivot code plascc. thank you

Comment: Does it run directly on sql server?

Comment: I would suggest your ODBC driver doesn't support case expressions inside a SUM()

Comment: i connect database in vb2010 and query it in vb

Comment: Try executing the statement using SSMS directly on SQL Server to ensure the statement is correct. Why do you use ODBC anyway instead of SQL Server's ADO.NET provider?

Comment: What RDBMS and version thereof are you running against?  Some support an actual `PIVOT` clause (like SQL Server) that would mean you don't need to use `CASE` at all...

Comment: The code looks [alright to me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aceb3/1)

Comment: this table is connect with microsoft ODBC data source

Comment: Please post the code that executes the statement and your connection string. Also make sure you can actually run the statement directly on the server (eg using Management Studio). It's impossible to help otherwise.

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to connect to MS Access or some other database instead of SQL Server? What's your connection string? If you are using an ODBC data source, what is the connection string stored there?

Comment: i connected this table is all ready.

Comment: and i click left at table and select new query.And then put query string like my question but it still error like that picture.

Answer (score 0):

on the assumption it's an ODBC driver limitation, perhaps nesting the case expressions as a subquery will help.

```
SELECT
      ARCBG_Abbrev
    , ARCIM_Code
    , SUM(O) AS O
    , SUM(I) AS I
    , SUM(F) AS F
FROM (
            SELECT
                  ARCBG_Abbrev
                , ARCIM_Code
                , CASE
                        WHEN TAR_Code = 'O' THEN
                              ITP_Price
                        ELSE
                              0
                  END AS O
                , CASE
                        WHEN TAR_Code = 'I' THEN
                              ITP_Price
                        ELSE
                              0
                  END AS I
                , CASE
                        WHEN TAR_Code = 'F' THEN
                              ITP_Price
                        ELSE
                              0
                  END AS F
            FROM SYSTEM.VS_OrderItem
      ) AS SQ
WHERE ARCIM_Code = '010004'
GROUP BY
      ARCBG_Abbrev
    , ARCIM_Code
```

Comment: same error message? it would be good to know if it does work in the dbms directly (what dbms and version is it?)

Comment: i see it in driver tab, name sql server is version 6.01.7601.17514.Are you mean this version

Comment: @user3001046 that's the ODBC driver's version, not SQL Server's version. Have you tried to run the statement on the server? Are you connecting to the right database?